# Dictionary changed size during iteration but I don't see where I've changed it

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to Python, so bear with me, but I've tried to create a script that gets synonyms to a word if I don't already have it and add it to my dictionary in JSON format.

Here is my code:

```
import json, sys, urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

f = open('dict.json', 'r')
string = json.loads(f.read())
tempString = string
url = 'http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/myapicode/%s/json'

def main():
    crawl()

def crawl():
    for a in string:
        for b in string[a]:
            for c in string[a][b]:
                for d in string[a][b][c]:
                    if not isInDict(d):
                        addWord(d, getWord(url % d))
                    else:
                        print('[-] Ignoring ' + d)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(tempString)
    f.truncate()
    f.close()

def isInDict(value):
    for x in list(tempString.keys()):
        if x == value:
            return True
    return False

def getWord(address):
    try:
        return urlopen(address).read().decode('utf-8')
    except:
        print('[!] Failed to get ' + address)
    return ''

def addWord(word, content):
    if content != None and content != '':
        print('[+] Adding ' + word)
        tempString[word] = content
    else:
        print('[!] Ignoring ' + word + ': content empty')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And when running, it works fine up until 'amour' and it give me this:

```
working fine
[+] Adding sex activity
[+] Adding sexual activity
[+] Adding sexual desire
[+] Adding sexual practice
[-] Ignoring amour
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "crawler.py", line 10, in main
    crawl()
  File "crawler.py", line 13, in crawl
    for a in string:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

But I don't see where I've change anything on `string` and only `tempString`...

PS: If you want the JSON data I read:

```
{
    "love": {
        "noun": {
            "syn": ["passion", "beloved", "dear", "dearest", "honey", "sexual love", "erotic love", "lovemaking", "making love", "love life", "concupiscence", "emotion", "eros", "loved one", "lover", "object", "physical attraction", "score", "sex", "sex activity", "sexual activity", "sexual desire", "sexual practice"],
            "ant": ["hate"],
            "usr": ["amour"]
        },
        "verb": {
            "syn": ["love", "enjoy", "roll in the hay", "make out", "make love", "sleep with", "get laid", "have sex", "know", "do it", "be intimate", "have intercourse", "have it away", "have it off", "screw", "jazz", "eff", "hump", "lie with", "bed", "have a go at it", "bang", "get it on", "bonk", "copulate", "couple", "like", "mate", "pair"],
            "ant": ["hate"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the cause of the problem, but your `isInDict()` function can be reduced to `return value in tempString`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line:

```
string = json.loads(f.read())
tempString = string
```

You assign `tempString` to refer to the same dictionary object as `string`. Then, in `addWord` you change `tempString`:

```
    tempString[word] = content
```

Because tempString is just another reference to the same dictionary object as `string`, that also changes `string`.

To avoid this, use:

```
import copy
tempString = copy.deepcopy(string)
```

Also, it's generally a bad practice to use variable names like `string` that are also the names of built in functions. It's not very descriptive, and it'll make you unable to access to built in function conveniently while the name is in scope.

Comment: Not to mention that neither tempString nor string is a string!

Comment: Thanks, you lead me in the right direction :)

Also, thanks people for all the little tips, I am aware of it not being a string and such, this was done very fast and is pretty messy, it's just to generate the 'synonym dictionary' that I need for the 'parent' project, though thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an example:

```
>>> for i in d:
...     if d[i] == 2:
...         d.pop(i)
...
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

To work around this, here is what is done:

```
>>> for i in d.keys():
...     if d[i] == 2:
...         d.pop(i)
...
>>> d
{'one': 1}
```

SO, for your specific code:

try changing this:

```
def crawl():
    for a in string:
```

to:

```
def crawl():
    for a in string.keys():
```

If this does not work, I will look in to your code in more depth at a later time today.